# R mutate across with a function or perhaps a function is not needed

Tags: r, dplyr

I've written a simple R function to take chemical below detection limit values, prefixed with "<", that takes the numeric part following the "<" symbol and divides it by two to return a half detection limit value.

This is the function:

```
    half_detection_limit <- function(x) {
      if(substr(x, 1, 1) == "<"){                        # Check to see if value starts with "<"
        detection <- substr(x, 2, nchar(x))              # Subset the number after "<"
        detection <- as.numeric(detection)               # Change it to a number
        half_detection <- detection/2                    # Divide it by two
        half_detection <- as.character(half_detection)   # Convert back to character 
        return(half_detection)                           # Return the result
      } else {                                           # otherwise
        return(x)                                        # return the value unchanged
      }                                          
     }
```

So if I run this as follows it works on any input of this format

```
> half_detection_limit("<0.002")
[1] "0.001"
```

Now consider a dummy data frame as follows:

```
A <- data.frame(t(c("A", "20", "<5", "6")))
B <- c("B", "10", "<10", "5")
C <- c("C", "<0.001", "2.5", "3.5")
D <- c("D", "0.02", "0.05", "1.3")

A <- rbind(A, B)
A <- rbind(A, C)
A <- rbind(A, D)

> A
  X1     X2   X3  X4
1  A     20   <5   6
2  B     10  <10   5
3  C <0.001  2.5 3.5
4  D   0.02 0.05 1.3
```

I would like to apply the half_detection limit function to this data frame using dplyr syntax to convert all below detection values in the data frame to half detection.  My failed attempt at doing this is as follows:

```
A <- A %>% 
     mutate(across(everything(), half_detection_limit))
```

The errors reported for this attempt are a follows:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(everything(), half_detection_limit)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `X1`.
Caused by error in `if (substr(x, 1, 1) == "<") ...`:
! the condition has length > 1
```

It appears that the function is being evaluated by the second error but I'm not understanding something here.

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way with a function? ... Should I be using mutate_at() instead?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: As you have prepared below ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here‘s a solution without the necessity of defining a function:

```
library(tidyverse)

A %>%
  mutate(across(-X1, ~ if_else(str_detect(., '<'),
                               as.character(as.numeric(str_remove(., '<')) / 2),
                               .)))

  X1    X2   X3  X4
1  A    20  2.5   6
2  B    10    5   5
3  C 5e-04  2.5 3.5
4  D  0.02 0.05 1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `if` you have made your function `half_detection_limit` scalar. You can use vectorized functions like `ifelse` or `case_when` to make it work for vectors.

```
half_detection_limit <- function(x) {
  ifelse(substr(x, 1, 1) == "<",  {                  # Check to see if value starts with "<"
    detection <- substr(x, 2, nchar(x))              # Subset the number after "<"
    detection <- as.numeric(detection)               # Change it to a number
    half_detection <- detection/2                    # Divide it by two
    half_detection <- as.character(half_detection)   # Convert back to character 
    half_detection
    },                                               # Return the result
    x)                                               # return the value unchanged
}
```

and then if you use your code it works -

```
A <- A %>% mutate(across(everything(), half_detection_limit))
A

#  X1     X2   X3  X4
#1  A     20  2.5   6
#2  B     10    5   5
#3  C 0.0005  2.5 3.5
#4  D   0.02 0.05 1.3
```